# webpack-dev-server not reloading browser

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I can't get webpack-dev-server to auto refresh browser, I have to terminate at command line and restart before the browser would load fresh content.
This is my webpack config:

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
        },
    })


    var debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
    console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
    module.exports = {
      context: __dirname + "/src",
      devtool: debug ? "inline-sourcemap" : null,
      entry: "./js/client.js,

      module: {
        loaders: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
              presets: ['react', 'es2015', 'stage-0'],
              plugins: ['react-html-attrs', 'transform-class-properties', 'transform-decorators-legacy'],
            }
          }
        ]
      },
 output: {
    path: __dirname + "src/",
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  plugins: debug ? [] : [
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ mangle: false, sourcemap: false }),
  ],
};
```

My package.json:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server  --content-base src --inline --hot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

I am on Windows and typed npm run dev on command line. I am using latest version of webpack and webpack-dev-server. Cant find anything online that could help.

Output:

```
C:\Users\owner\react\basic-react>npm run dev

> basic-react@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\owner\react\basic-react
> webpack-dev-server  --content-base src --inline --hot


http://localhost:8080/
webpack result is served from /
content is served from C:\Users\owner\react\basic-react\src
Hash: 0e903e041e328deb3d40
Version: webpack 1.13.1
Time: 1959ms
        Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
client.min.js  2.4 MB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} client.min.js (main) 868 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 52 bytes {0} [built]
    [1] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 2.67 kB {0} [built]
    [2] ./~/url/url.js 22.3 kB {0} [built]
    [3] ./~/url/~/punycode/punycode.js 14.6 kB {0} [built]
    [4] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 251 bytes {0} [built]
    [5] ./~/querystring/index.js 127 bytes {0} [built]
    [6] ./~/querystring/decode.js 2.4 kB {0} [built]
    [7] ./~/querystring/encode.js 2.09 kB {0} [built]
    [8] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/entry.js 244 bytes {0} [built]
    [9] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport-list.js 613 bytes {0} [built]
   [10] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/websocket.js 2.71 kB {0} [built]
   [11] ./~/process/browser.js 2.82 kB {0} [built]
   [12] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/event.js 2 kB {0} [built]
   [13] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/random.js 746 bytes {0} [built]
   [14] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser-crypto.js 438 bytes {0} [built]
   [15] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/url.js 975 bytes {0} [built]
   [16] ./~/url-parse/index.js 8.09 kB {0} [built]
   [17] ./~/requires-port/index.js 753 bytes {0} [built]
   [18] ./~/url-parse/lolcation.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [19] ./~/querystringify/index.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
   [20] ./~/debug/browser.js 3.76 kB {0} [built]
   [21] ./~/debug/debug.js 4.1 kB {0} [built]
   [22] ./~/ms/index.js 2.33 kB {0} [built]
   [23] ./~/inherits/inherits_browser.js 672 bytes {0} [built]
   [24] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/emitter.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
   [25] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
   [26] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/websocket.js 172 bytes {0} [built]
   [27] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-streaming.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
   [28] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/ajax-based.js 1.31 kB {0} [built]
   [29] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/sender-receiver.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
   [30] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/buffered-sender.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
   [31] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/polling.js 1.32 kB {0} [built]
   [32] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/xhr.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [33] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-cors.js 343 bytes {0} [built]
   [34] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/abstract-xhr.js 4.8 kB {0} [built]
   [35] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-local.js 352 bytes {0} [built]
   [36] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/browser.js 560 bytes {0} [built]
   [37] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-streaming.js 984 bytes {0} [built]
   [38] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xdr.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [39] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/eventsource.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
   [40] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/eventsource.js 1.58 kB {0} [built]
   [41] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/browser/eventsource.js 37 bytes {0} [built]
   [42] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/lib/iframe-wrap.js 981 bytes {0} [built]
   [43] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/iframe.js 3.83 kB {0} [built]
   [44] ./~/json3/lib/json3.js 43.3 kB {0} [built]
   [45] (webpack)/buildin/amd-options.js 43 bytes {0} [built]
   [46] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/version.js 26 bytes {0} [built]
   [47] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/iframe.js 5.06 kB {0} [built]
   [48] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/object.js 532 bytes {0} [built]
   [49] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/htmlfile.js 710 bytes {0} [built]
   [50] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/htmlfile.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
   [51] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xhr-polling.js 894 bytes {0} [built]
   [52] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/xdr-polling.js 712 bytes {0} [built]
   [53] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/jsonp-polling.js 1.02 kB {0} [built]
   [54] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/receiver/jsonp.js 5.57 kB {0} [built]
   [55] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/jsonp.js 2.46 kB {0} [built]
   [56] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/main.js 11.9 kB {0} [built]
   [57] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/shims.js 18.2 kB {0} [built]
   [58] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/escape.js 2.31 kB {0} [built]
   [59] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/transport.js 1.35 kB {0} [built]
   [60] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/utils/log.js 450 bytes {0} [built]
   [61] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/event.js 477 bytes {0} [built]
   [62] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/location.js 177 bytes {0} [built]
   [63] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/close.js 295 bytes {0} [built]
   [64] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/event/trans-message.js 292 bytes {0} [built]
   [65] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-receiver.js 2.22 kB {0} [built]
   [66] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/transport/sender/xhr-fake.js 456 bytes {0} [built]
   [67] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe.js 1.52 kB {0} [built]
   [68] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-iframe-receiver.js 791 bytes {0} [built]
   [69] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/info-ajax.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
   [70] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/iframe-bootstrap.js 2.9 kB {0} [built]
   [71] ./~/sockjs-client/lib/facade.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
   [72] ./~/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {0} [built]
   [73] ./~/ansi-regex/index.js 135 bytes {0} [built]
   [74] (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js 1.85 kB {0} [built]
   [75] (webpack)/hot/log-apply-result.js 813 bytes {0} [built]
   [76] ./src/js/client.js 508 bytes {0} [built]
   [77] ./~/react/react.js 56 bytes {0} [built]
   [78] ./~/react/lib/React.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
   [79] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOM.js 3.71 kB {0} [built]
   [80] ./~/react/lib/ReactCurrentOwner.js 653 bytes {0} [built]
   [81] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextComponent.js 4.32 kB {0} [built]
   [82] ./~/react/lib/DOMChildrenOperations.js 5 kB {0} [built]
   [83] ./~/react/lib/Danger.js 6.96 kB {0} [built]
   [84] ./~/fbjs/lib/ExecutionEnvironment.js 1.09 kB {0} [built]
   [85] ./~/fbjs/lib/createNodesFromMarkup.js 2.71 kB {0} [built]
   [86] ./~/fbjs/lib/createArrayFromMixed.js 2.36 kB {0} [built]
   [87] ./~/fbjs/lib/toArray.js 1.98 kB {0} [built]
   [88] ./~/fbjs/lib/invariant.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
   [89] ./~/fbjs/lib/getMarkupWrap.js 3.06 kB {0} [built]
   [90] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyFunction.js 1.09 kB {0} [built]
   [91] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChildUpdateTypes.js 861 bytes {0} [built]
   [92] ./~/fbjs/lib/keyMirror.js 1.27 kB {0} [built]
   [93] ./~/react/lib/ReactPerf.js 2.51 kB {0} [built]
   [94] ./~/react/lib/setInnerHTML.js 3.35 kB {0} [built]
   [95] ./~/react/lib/setTextContent.js 1.2 kB {0} [built]
   [96] ./~/react/lib/escapeTextContentForBrowser.js 849 bytes {0} [built]
   [97] ./~/react/lib/DOMPropertyOperations.js 7.88 kB {0} [built]
   [98] ./~/react/lib/DOMProperty.js 9.57 kB {0} [built]
   [99] ./~/react/lib/quoteAttributeValueForBrowser.js 746 bytes {0} [built]
  [100] ./~/fbjs/lib/warning.js 1.77 kB {0} [built]
  [101] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentBrowserEnvironment.js 1.26 kB {0} [built]
  [102] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMIDOperations.js 3.29 kB {0} [built]
  [103] ./~/react/lib/ReactMount.js 36.8 kB {0} [built]
  [104] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserEventEmitter.js 12.4 kB {0} [built]
  [105] ./~/react/lib/EventConstants.js 2.04 kB {0} [built]
  [106] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginHub.js 9.22 kB {0} [built]
  [107] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginRegistry.js 8.41 kB {0} [built]
  [108] ./~/react/lib/EventPluginUtils.js 6.79 kB {0} [built]
  [109] ./~/react/lib/ReactErrorUtils.js 2.27 kB {0} [built]
  [110] ./~/react/lib/accumulateInto.js 1.74 kB {0} [built]
  [111] ./~/react/lib/forEachAccumulated.js 893 bytes {0} [built]
  [112] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventEmitterMixin.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
  [113] ./~/react/lib/ViewportMetrics.js 638 bytes {0} [built]
  [114] ./~/react/lib/Object.assign.js 1.26 kB {0} [built]
  [115] ./~/react/lib/isEventSupported.js 1.97 kB {0} [built]
  [116] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFeatureFlags.js 458 bytes {0} [built]
  [117] ./~/react/lib/ReactElement.js 8.07 kB {0} [built]
  [118] ./~/react/lib/canDefineProperty.js 629 bytes {0} [built]
  [119] ./~/react/lib/ReactEmptyComponentRegistry.js 1.38 kB {0} [built]
  [120] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceHandles.js 10.6 kB {0} [built]
  [121] ./~/react/lib/ReactRootIndex.js 723 bytes {0} [built]
  [122] ./~/react/lib/ReactInstanceMap.js 1.25 kB {0} [built]
  [123] ./~/react/lib/ReactMarkupChecksum.js 1.39 kB {0} [built]
  [124] ./~/react/lib/adler32.js 1.2 kB {0} [built]
  [125] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconciler.js 3.55 kB {0} [built]
  [126] ./~/react/lib/ReactRef.js 2.34 kB {0} [built]
  [127] ./~/react/lib/ReactOwner.js 3.45 kB {0} [built]
  [128] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdateQueue.js 10.9 kB {0} [built]
  [129] ./~/react/lib/ReactUpdates.js 8.54 kB {0} [built]
  [130] ./~/react/lib/CallbackQueue.js 2.44 kB {0} [built]
  [131] ./~/react/lib/PooledClass.js 3.55 kB {0} [built]
  [132] ./~/react/lib/Transaction.js 9.55 kB {0} [built]
  [133] ./~/fbjs/lib/emptyObject.js 482 bytes {0} [built]
  [134] ./~/fbjs/lib/containsNode.js 1.43 kB {0} [built]
  [135] ./~/fbjs/lib/isTextNode.js 628 bytes {0} [built]
  [136] ./~/fbjs/lib/isNode.js 712 bytes {0} [built]
  [137] ./~/react/lib/instantiateReactComponent.js 4.52 kB {0} [built]
  [138] ./~/react/lib/ReactCompositeComponent.js 27.5 kB {0} [built]
  [139] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponentEnvironment.js 1.67 kB {0} [built]
  [140] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocations.js 549 bytes {0} [built]
  [141] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypeLocationNames.js 611 bytes {0} [built]
  [142] ./~/react/lib/shouldUpdateReactComponent.js 1.49 kB {0} [built]
  [143] ./~/react/lib/ReactEmptyComponent.js 1.8 kB {0} [built]
  [144] ./~/react/lib/ReactNativeComponent.js 3.02 kB {0} [built]
  [145] ./~/react/lib/validateDOMNesting.js 13.1 kB {0} [built]
  [146] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultInjection.js 3.99 kB {0} [built]
  [147] ./~/react/lib/BeforeInputEventPlugin.js 14.9 kB {0} [built]
  [148] ./~/react/lib/EventPropagators.js 5.22 kB {0} [built]
  [149] ./~/react/lib/FallbackCompositionState.js 2.49 kB {0} [built]
  [150] ./~/react/lib/getTextContentAccessor.js 994 bytes {0} [built]
  [151] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticCompositionEvent.js 1.16 kB {0} [built]
  [152] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticEvent.js 5.79 kB {0} [built]
  [153] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticInputEvent.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
  [154] ./~/fbjs/lib/keyOf.js 1.11 kB {0} [built]
  [155] ./~/react/lib/ChangeEventPlugin.js 11.5 kB {0} [built]
  [156] ./~/react/lib/getEventTarget.js 930 bytes {0} [built]
  [157] ./~/react/lib/isTextInputElement.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
  [158] ./~/react/lib/ClientReactRootIndex.js 551 bytes {0} [built]
  [159] ./~/react/lib/DefaultEventPluginOrder.js 1.26 kB {0} [built]
  [160] ./~/react/lib/EnterLeaveEventPlugin.js 3.9 kB {0} [built]
  [161] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticMouseEvent.js 2.2 kB {0} [built]
  [162] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticUIEvent.js 1.64 kB {0} [built]
  [163] ./~/react/lib/getEventModifierState.js 1.3 kB {0} [built]
  [164] ./~/react/lib/HTMLDOMPropertyConfig.js 7.63 kB {0} [built]
  [165] ./~/react/lib/ReactBrowserComponentMixin.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
  [166] ./~/react/lib/findDOMNode.js 2.17 kB {0} [built]
  [167] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js 1.92 kB {0} [built]
  [168] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMComponent.js 36.9 kB {0} [built]
  [169] ./~/react/lib/AutoFocusUtils.js 816 bytes {0} [built]
  [170] ./~/fbjs/lib/focusNode.js 725 bytes {0} [built]
  [171] ./~/react/lib/CSSPropertyOperations.js 5.71 kB {0} [built]
  [172] ./~/react/lib/CSSProperty.js 3.5 kB {0} [built]
  [173] ./~/fbjs/lib/camelizeStyleName.js 1.03 kB {0} [built]
  [174] ./~/fbjs/lib/camelize.js 729 bytes {0} [built]
  [175] ./~/react/lib/dangerousStyleValue.js 1.93 kB {0} [built]
  [176] ./~/fbjs/lib/hyphenateStyleName.js 1 kB {0} [built]
  [177] ./~/fbjs/lib/hyphenate.js 822 bytes {0} [built]
  [178] ./~/fbjs/lib/memoizeStringOnly.js 778 bytes {0} [built]
  [179] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMButton.js 1.15 kB {0} [built]
  [180] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMInput.js 5.74 kB {0} [built]
  [181] ./~/react/lib/LinkedValueUtils.js 5.18 kB {0} [built]
  [182] ./~/react/lib/ReactPropTypes.js 12.3 kB {0} [built]
  [183] ./~/react/lib/getIteratorFn.js 1.17 kB {0} [built]
  [184] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMOption.js 2.82 kB {0} [built]
  [185] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildren.js 5.83 kB {0} [built]
  [186] ./~/react/lib/traverseAllChildren.js 6.9 kB {0} [built]
  [187] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelect.js 6.11 kB {0} [built]
  [188] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMTextarea.js 4.35 kB {0} [built]
  [189] ./~/react/lib/ReactMultiChild.js 14.7 kB {0} [built]
  [190] ./~/react/lib/ReactChildReconciler.js 4.52 kB {0} [built]
  [191] ./~/react/lib/flattenChildren.js 1.65 kB {0} [built]
  [192] ./~/fbjs/lib/shallowEqual.js 1.28 kB {0} [built]
  [193] ./~/react/lib/ReactEventListener.js 7.51 kB {0} [built]
  [194] ./~/fbjs/lib/EventListener.js 2.65 kB {0} [built]
  [195] ./~/fbjs/lib/getUnboundedScrollPosition.js 1.09 kB {0} [built]
  [196] ./~/react/lib/ReactInjection.js 1.37 kB {0} [built]
  [197] ./~/react/lib/ReactClass.js 27.8 kB {0} [built]
  [198] ./~/react/lib/ReactComponent.js 5.04 kB {0} [built]
  [199] ./~/react/lib/ReactNoopUpdateQueue.js 3.94 kB {0} [built]
  [200] ./~/react/lib/ReactReconcileTransaction.js 4.58 kB {0} [built]
  [201] ./~/react/lib/ReactInputSelection.js 4.32 kB {0} [built]
  [202] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMSelection.js 6.83 kB {0} [built]
  [203] ./~/react/lib/getNodeForCharacterOffset.js 1.66 kB {0} [built]
  [204] ./~/fbjs/lib/getActiveElement.js 924 bytes {0} [built]
  [205] ./~/react/lib/SelectEventPlugin.js 6.71 kB {0} [built]
  [206] ./~/react/lib/ServerReactRootIndex.js 868 bytes {0} [built]
  [207] ./~/react/lib/SimpleEventPlugin.js 17.4 kB {0} [built]
  [208] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticClipboardEvent.js 1.23 kB {0} [built]
  [209] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticFocusEvent.js 1.12 kB {0} [built]
  [210] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticKeyboardEvent.js 2.76 kB {0} [built]
  [211] ./~/react/lib/getEventCharCode.js 1.56 kB {0} [built]
  [212] ./~/react/lib/getEventKey.js 2.93 kB {0} [built]
  [213] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticDragEvent.js 1.13 kB {0} [built]
  [214] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticTouchEvent.js 1.33 kB {0} [built]
  [215] ./~/react/lib/SyntheticWheelEvent.js 1.99 kB {0} [built]
  [216] ./~/react/lib/SVGDOMPropertyConfig.js 3.8 kB {0} [built]
  [217] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultPerf.js 8.63 kB {0} [built]
  [218] ./~/react/lib/ReactDefaultPerfAnalysis.js 5.79 kB {0} [built]
  [219] ./~/fbjs/lib/performanceNow.js 844 bytes {0} [built]
  [220] ./~/fbjs/lib/performance.js 612 bytes {0} [built]
  [221] ./~/react/lib/ReactVersion.js 379 bytes {0} [built]
  [222] ./~/react/lib/renderSubtreeIntoContainer.js 463 bytes {0} [built]
  [223] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMServer.js 766 bytes {0} [built]
  [224] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRendering.js 3.3 kB {0} [built]
  [225] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerBatchingStrategy.js 673 bytes {0} [built]
  [226] ./~/react/lib/ReactServerRenderingTransaction.js 2.3 kB {0} [built]
  [227] ./~/react/lib/ReactIsomorphic.js 2.05 kB {0} [built]
  [228] ./~/react/lib/ReactDOMFactories.js 3.36 kB {0} [built]
  [229] ./~/react/lib/ReactElementValidator.js 10.8 kB {0} [built]
  [230] ./~/fbjs/lib/mapObject.js 1.47 kB {0} [built]
  [231] ./~/react/lib/onlyChild.js 1.21 kB {0} [built]
  [232] ./~/react/lib/deprecated.js 1.77 kB {0} [built]
  [233] ./~/react-dom/index.js 63 bytes {0} [built]
  [234] ./src/js/components/Layout.js 2.84 kB {0} [built]
  [235] ./src/js/components/Footer.js 2.33 kB {0} [built]
  [236] ./src/js/components/Header.js 2.35 kB {0} [built]
  [237] ./src/js/components/Header/Title.js 2.32 kB {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Comment: What version of webpack/webpack-dev-server? What is your output when you do run it?  Does the same happen when you run it outside of an npm script?  You also don't need to specify a relative path to webpack-dev-server, since you are running it in an npm context, just the command "webpack-dev-server" will suffice.

Comment: webpack 1.13.1, webpack-dev-server 1.14.1.  It's the same when I typed it in the command line.

Comment: Are you in your browser loading the link `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/index.html`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is usually caused by native watcher that don't detect changes. If you're using an IDE that supports "safe write" like Webstorm, just disable that option. Safe write writes a new file, and then replaces the original instead of changing the original. This confuses the native file watchers.

You can also use polling instead of native watchers. Add this to your webpack config:

```
watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300, // Delay the rebuilt after the first change. Value is a time in ms.
    poll: true // bool - enable / disable polling or number - polling delay 
}
```

Comment: That didn't work. I am using Visual Studio Code, also tried with Sublime.

Comment: If the polling doesn't work, this isn't the problem. Try --watch instead of --hot in the command line, . If that doesn't help, maybe you should started from a boilerplate like [react-hot-boilerplate](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate), and customize it.